# Infinite Output in case Statement java

Tags: java, while-loop, switch-statement, do-while

I am accepting input from user in the form of a string (which contains both char & int) .I am further dividing string into char & int and using char in case statement,but my case statement giving me infinite loop.I am not able to figure out the error..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    
    String str=sc.nextLine();
    
        String[] part = str.split("\\s+");
        
      do 
      { 
          
         switch(part[0])
         {
          case "AB":
              System.out.println("hi");
              int data=Integer.parseInt(part[1]);
              System.out.println(data);
              break;
          case "PR":
              System.out.println("printining");
              break;
          case "AE":
              System.out.println("AE");
               break;
          case "EXIT":
              System.exit(0);
              break;
         }
      }
      while(true);
        
}
```

Comment: You don't change `part` inside the loop; so unless you enter EXIT initially, it's going to keep looping.

Comment: Why do you have a loop here?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Because i want to continue the loop till user enter EXIT command

Answer (score 1):

You don't change `part` inside the loop; so unless you enter EXIT initially, it's going to keep looping.

Move the two lines above the loop into the loop:

```
do
{
    String str = sc.nextLine();

    String[] part = str.split("\\s+");

    // Rest of loop body.
```

Answer (score 1):

break statement quit the switch not the loop, and the loop condition is ALWAYS true!